# Android Studio create project generate colors.xml with junk characters

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, encoding, android-studio-3.0

Suddenly my Android Studio always generates the colors.xml file with junk characters when creating a new project. I have scoured the internet and found no answer. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 which I just updated recently. But, the problem already occurred in the previous version. At first, I thought that this is an encoding problem, but my settings already specify UTF-8 for all files. Also, opening the same file in other text editors display the same result.

Of course, I can just edit and replace the colors.xml file with the correct content. But, I fear this problem will escalate in the future if I leave them.

Here is a screenshot of the file in question:
[image: colors.xml error]

Here is the screenshot of my setting:
[image]

Comment: Can you try changing your Project Encoding to <System Default: windows-1252> and also the Default encoding for properties file: <System Default: windows-1252>. See how does that impact the color.xml file

Comment: The original encoding for those settings were windows-1252. The problem started occurring back then. I changed those to utf-8 and tried to create new project. It's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let me post an answer for future reference. The problem was solved by uninstalling Android Studio and clearing all settings. After I reinstall Android Studio the problem was corrected.

On Windows 10, I chose "clear user settings" while uninstalling. I also deleted the **.AndroidStudio** and **.AndroidStudio3.2** folders in "C:\Users[user]\" after I backup those folders. After that, I reinstall Android Studio and redo all the settings. Now my Android Studio can create a new project without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.2.1
I found a solution! Just delete user settings folder ..\Users\%USERNAME%\ .AndroidStudio3.2