# Error: Xml declaration should proceed all document content (auto generated java code in colors.xml)

Tags: android

> Xml declaration should proceed all document content

Suddenly I am getting this error in my android project and i have not made any changes , but yet this popped up ,with some auto generated java code.

[image]

have tried commenting the above , but thats not working so 
tried adding the following code to make it correct

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="your_color">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

still nothing happened.

[image: this is the error]

Comment: What is the actual problem, It's not clear from attachment.

Comment: i am getting this error :
Content is not allowed in prolog

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: Are you adding Java code to an XML file? That might be the issue.

Comment: Check specially 2nd solution

Comment: What are the contents of your `color.xml`?

Comment: no i have not added any code till the error popped up the first image shows auto generated code . Later on i have added some xml code which is in the second image.

Comment: package com.example.food_donate;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="your_color">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>


@Edric

Comment: Yup - just as I've suspected, you _have_ entered Java code into an XML file. Simply remove the Java code to fix the issue.

Comment: Have a look at these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52914091, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52909918.

Answer (score 3):

Because a space is created before the first line of code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because XML files should only contain valid XML markup and not contain Java code. Change the contents of your XML file to exclude the Java code by either commenting it out with `<!-- (Contents of comment) -->` or by deleting the Java code altogether.

Comment: commenting was not working ... deletion worked ... thanks

Comment: @AnkitaBasu Just curious, but how did you end up pasting Java code into an XML file in the first place?

Comment: @AnkitaBasu, Commenting should also work. `<!--package com.example.food_donate; 
import androidx.annotation.NonNull; 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat; 
import android.Manifest; 
import android.content-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color> 
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color> 
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color> 
    <color name="your_color">#FFFFFF</color> 
</resources>`

Comment: Yes I have seen. I just reply to her comment, otherwise I added it as Answer ;)

Comment: i did not paste that java code in the  Xml file , it got auto generated . This is the reason i got confused in the , that how come some java code is getting generated there in the first place .Why would i do such blunder . @Edric